# Label of Bars are not showing on top of bar using core plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am able to draw a stacked bar graph with the help of core plot. My problem is i am not able to place the label on top of stacked bar graph. To create bar i have done following things

[image]

```
for (NSString *set in [[barChartidentifiers allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]) {
    CPTBarPlot *plot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    CGColorRef color = ((UIColor *)[barChartidentifiers objectForKey:set]).CGColor;
    plot.fill  = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color]];
    if (firstPlot) {
        plot.barBasesVary = NO;
        firstPlot  = NO;
    } else {
        plot.barBasesVary = YES;
    }
    plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.5);
    plot.barsAreHorizontal  = NO;
    plot.labelTextStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.identifier = set;
    [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
}
```

and below is the code i am writing in

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    NSNumber *num;
    if (fieldEnum == 0) {
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    }

    else {
        double offset = 0;
        if (((CPTBarPlot *)plot).barBasesVary) {
            for (NSString *set in [[barChartidentifiers allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]) {
                if ([plot.identifier isEqual:set]) {
                    break;
                }
                offset += [[[data objectForKey:[dates objectAtIndex:index]] objectForKey:set] doubleValue];


            }
        }

        //Y Value
        if (fieldEnum == 1) {
            num =[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[[data objectForKey:[dates objectAtIndex:index]] objectForKey:plot.identifier] doubleValue] + offset];
        }

        //Offset for stacked bar
        else {
            num =[NSNumber numberWithDouble:offset];
        }
    }

    //NSLog(@"%@ - %d - %d - %f", plot.identifier, index, fieldEnum, num);

    return num;
}
```

Comment: You should use the enum values for the plot fields instead of magic numbers: `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation`, `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip`, and `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to adjust the `labelOffset` of each plot. Try a negative value to put the label over its plot rather than getting stuck under another plot.

Another thing to try would be to add the plots in the reverse order so lower plots and their labels are on top of the ones above. In your example, the yellow plot would be first, green second, etc.

If all else fails, make your own labels using plot space annotations. This would give more flexibility in positioning the labels, too. For example, you could put the labels next to the bars instead of on top.

Comment: Thanks Eric labelOffset works for me.can you please clarify that  what is the difference between CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation and CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase?

Comment: The bar location is the position of the bar along the axis (x-axis for vertical bars and y-axis for horizontal bars). The tip value is one end of the bar. The base value is the other end of the bar. If `barBasesVary` is `NO`, all bars share the plot's `baseValue`. If `YES`, the datasource will be queried for the `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase` value for each bar.